# set state and access updated state in a same function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can we access updated states in the same function?

```
state = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
  };

  updateState = () => {
    const { a, b } = this.state;

    console.log("previous a", a);
    console.log("previous b", b);

    this.setState({ a: b, b: 3 });

    console.log("New a", a); <-- getting previous value here
    console.log("New b", b); <-- getting previous value here

  };
```

is it possible to get a new value in the same function?

async and await are not working here. function method where we apply function as a 2nd parameter to the setstate is not working for the whole application.

please do not flag this question.

Comment: You cannot do it because of how react works. State updates are async. What is the need to do this? You might want to recheck your approach. Add that to the question and you will get a suitable way to amendit

Comment: `this.state.a` is always the previous/current value. Whatever you want to set with `setState` is the next/new value. Pick whichever you want.

Comment: i've used something like `this.state.a = this.state.b` `this.state.b = 3` but getting the warning here do not mutate the state instead uses setstate.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `this.setState`'s callback in this way:

```
state = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
  };

  updateState = () => {
    const { a, b } = this.state;

    console.log("previous a", a);
    console.log("previous b", b);

    this.setState({ a: b, b: 3 }, () => {
       console.log("New a", this.state.a);
       console.log("New b", this.state.b);
    });
  };
```

**EDIT** to print new state values you could use also `componentDidUpdate` in this way:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.a !== this.state.a) {
    console.log("New a", this.state.a);
  }
  if (prevState.b !== this.state.b) {
    console.log("New b", this.state.b);
  }
}
```

Comment: this functionality i've applied on a component. although it does work but not for the whole application... I've got to know componentDidUpdate() is used for this. did anyone know how  componentDidUpdate() method applied here?

Comment: @DiwanshuTyagi I updated my answer with `componentDidUpdate` case.

Answer (score -1):

you are using a local constant variable whose value is not changed. so if you want to use updated value use **this.state.a** and **this.state.b** for respective value.

```
  state = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
  };

  updateState = () => {
    const { a, b } = this.state;

    console.log("previous a", a);
    console.log("previous b", b);

    this.setState({ a: b, b: 3 });

    console.log("New a", a); <-- getting previous value here  // problem is here
    console.log("New b", b); <-- getting previous value here  // problem is here
    //replace above code with below code 
    console.log("New a", this.state.a);  //replace with this code.
    console.log("New b", this.state.b); //replace with this code

  };
```